# asp.net mvc 3: store stylesheets, images and javascript in shared library

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an asp.net mvc 3 project that uses Razor. I am able to store the views in a shared library, but I also want to store additional resources like images, stylesheets and javascript files in a shared library. So my question is:

How can I store stylesheets, javascript and images in a shared library?

Comment: What exactly do you m ean by a shared library? Do you mean a folder like the one called Shared in which the views are stored?

Comment: I mean a Class Library in Visual Studio that I can share between multiple projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to share static resources such as images, stylesheets and javascript files between multiple projects I would recommend you creating a separate web application that will host those resources and which will be accessed by all other applications. A sort of CDN if you will. The benefit of a CDN is that all applications have a single location for those static resources meaning that clients of all applications will have those resources in cache.

If you want to store them in a separate assembly that would mean that each application will have a different copy of them => clients of your applications won't benefit from this caching. You could still do it if you will. Simply embed those resources into the library and then write a controller action that will read them and serve them.

Comment: How do I access an embedded resource from a controller?

Comment: @redeeze, you could use the [GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx) method.